# Getting in common connections in a chat messages database using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I need to perform a complex query on a fairly simple table that stores chat messages. The table has the following columns:

```
|message_id|from|to|body|
```

The `from` and `to` fields contains user IDs which are just encoded as integers. In the app, there is a conversation between user `A` and user `B` if user `A` has sent a message to user `B` and vice versa. My problem now is that for user `A`, I need to query all persons that `A` has in common with `B` regarding conversations.

So for example, if user `A` has a conversation with user `B` and `D` and user `B` has a conversation with user `C` and I need to query all common users of `A` and `B`, the result set will only consist of `C`. `D` is not included since user `B` has no conversation with user `D`.

I have experience with MySQL but I have no clue where to start here. I prefer to do this (complex) query in one run but I wonder if there exists an efficient algorithm with multiple queries to do this task.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: when A is in a multichat with B and D, if A sends a message you should insert 2 rows in your table: `row1 = 'A', 'B', 'HelloWorld';`  `row2 = 'A', 'D', 'HelloWorld';` this way you can trace every single message.

Comment: So.... was my answer wrong or have you forgotten about this question?

Comment: @GGG: I didn't have time yet to look further into your answer but definitely will!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a subquery for that prupose:

```
SELECT to FROM Test WHERE from = 'A' AND to IN (SELECT to FROM Test WHERE from = 'B')
```